# how to add record to array

Tags: javascript, html, web, ember.js

I'm beginner in Emberjs, so i need to pass selected item in list to basket.
I have route catalog

```
  <div class="flexbox">
{{left-menu-bar}}
<div class="main">
  {{side-basket items=items}}
  <div class="catalog-container">
    <div class="container-inner">
        {{#list-filter filter=(action 'filterByName') as |resultItems i|}}
        <ul class="responsive-table">
          <li class="table-header" >
            <div class="col col-1">Наименование</div>
            <div class="col col-2 radio-group">Год<i class="fas fa-angle-up angle angle-left radio" note="up" {{action 'sortColumn' value="target.note"}}></i><i class="fas fa-angle-down angle radio" data-value="down"></i></div>
            <div class="col col-3">Количество<i class="fas fa-angle-up angle angle-left radio"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-down angle"></i></div>
            <div class="col col-4">Цена<i class="fas fa-angle-up angle angle-left"></i><i class="fas fa-angle-down angle"></i></div>
            <div class="col col-5">Примечание</div>
          </li>
          {{#each resultItems as |itemUnit|}}
            {{item-list item=itemUnit  gotItem=(action 'getBasketItem')}}
          {{/each}}
        </ul>
          {{/list-filter}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

catalog.js controller

```
export default Controller.extend({
items: [],
actions: {
  filterByName(param) {
    if (param !== '') {
      return this.get('store').query('item', {name: param})
    }
  }
  getBasketItem(param){
    if (param !== '') {
      var item = this.get('store').query('item', {name: param});
      //how to add item in items to use in side-basket
    }
}
}
});
```

component item-list.hbs

```
<li class="table-row hvr-grow" {{action 'handleItem' item.name}}>
  {{yield result}}
  <div class="col col-1" data-label="Наименование">{{item.name}}</div>
  <div class="col col-2" data-label="Год">{{item.year}}</div>
  <div class="col col-3" data-label="Количество">{{item.quantity}}</div>
  <div class="col col-4" data-label="Цена">{{item.cost}}</div>
  <div class="col col-5" data-label="Примечание">{{item.info}}</div>
</li>
```

item-list.js

```
    export default Ember.Component.extend({
    selectedIndex : false,
    actions: {
     handleItem(param) {
     let handledItem = this.get('gotItem');
     handledItem(param);
   }
 }
});
```

and side-basket component with nested basket-list component

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn4qq.png)

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ZfK.png)

[test with manual writing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al1oN.png)

how to realise this transfer?

Answer (score 0):

In the long-run, you will find it easier if you move your data fetching to your route rather than the controller and just use query params in the controller. If you make this change, when you set your filter you can update the query params, which will in turn cause the router to refresh the model. The Ember docs explain this quite well on this page:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/

and you also need to look at this section:

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition

Note: `this.get('store').query('item', {name: param})` in `getBasketItem` is returning a promise. If you change to fetching your data in the route using query params, you will be able to access your data via `this.get('model')` in your component and reference `model` in your route template - both of which will be the resolved data rather than a promise.

That should then simplify your code and make it easier to work with actual items in the controller and component. Rather than needing to fetch the item from the store in `getBasketItem`, you should be able to pass the item as a parameter and push it onto your items property with something like `this.get('items').pushObject(selectedItem)`.